# How to undo an account renaming without having to make a system restore in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, wireless-networking, ssd, user-accounts

First of all, I must say that my concern may seem perfectionist. But I have this concern because of the old reputation of Windows operating systems in terms of bugs; and also some strange things that I noticed at the last two days.

I have a **Dell Inspiron 14R** for about 5 years. Last month, it became abnormally slow and the problem was HDD. About 60 bad sectors. I think it was caused by a malware, even if several sources say that it's a rare thing.

So, two days ago my notebook returned from a repair service, with an SSD installed with **Windows 10 Home Single Language** (no backup needed). It's working fast and, as a bonus, my Wi-Fi is working again. But it came with a single administrator account named 'user'. I wanted to change it, but I was too impatient to make a good search. So I tried the Control Panel first. But, the user folder name wasn't changed. Then, I tried running `Control UserPasswords2` and make the change there.

I ended up running that command again and here comes the first bug:

- *The users list was empty*

But that was solved after reboot. Profile changed, but the folder name remained the same.

- At some moment, *I noticed that my home wireless network was duplicated*.

I could use both at the same time. I removed one or both networks and, until now, it's fine. Temp folder wasn't duplicated.

I didn't touch registry and I don't want to work with it. So, now, I just want to get back to the previous state, renaming the profile back to 'user'. Also, I want to create a basic user for me. And, maybe, get rid of 'user' creating a new, dedicated, administrator. It sounds simple, but does it open any security hole? Reinstalling the system would be an overkill and bad for SSD lifespan. And considering that I needed to try two different companies to get things right, I'm afraid of messing thing up again.

Comment: Is the option ‘Recover System to a previous state’ activate on your machine or not?
If it is, select a date in the calendar like thingy where a ‘restore’ point has been created and click on ‘restore’.
This wont do any changes on your ‘files’, it’ll only change system settings, …

Comment: Did you mean a restore point? Or "Fresh Start"?

Comment: I meant ‘restore point’.

Comment: It has only one restore point dating at 12/07, Windows Update. But it was created before I get my notebook back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you messed up things a bit. Though I don't have a direct solution but I do have a little roundabout way which is little long and time consuming but I think you'll like it.

- First open a command prompt in elevated mode(How to do that?)
- Type `cmd` in start menu and `Right click` in `Command` and choose `Run as administrator`.
- Press `Yes` in UAC confirmation dialogue box.
- Now type `net user administrator /active:yes`

Now reboot your computer(logoff is also fine) and choose `Administrator` as your new login account instead of existing username(whatever was by default or you modified).

It will take some time to create new profile but bear with it. After, it is over and you gain access to desktop. Open command prompt again.

- Type `net user your_modified_username /delete` and it will delete the user.
- Now, type `sysdm.cpl` and press `Enter` again.

A new windows will open now. Click on `Advanced` tab and on `Settings` under `User Profiles` and it will look something like this.

[image: User Profiles]

- Choose `Account Unknown` and press `Delete`. Make sure that it is your modified account and not something else. Also don't delete `Default Profile` unless you want to break your system.
- Now press `Ok` and close the window.
- Use File Explorer and go to `C:\Users` and check if the old user's folder is still present. And if it is, then manually delete it.
- Now back to command prompt again.
- Create new user by typing `net user my_name my_password /add` (password is optional).
- Add it to administrator group by typing: `net localgroup administrators my_name /add`
- Now exit the command prompt and restart your computer again.
- Now choose new login username that you've created in login screen and wait again to complete it's creating user profile.

We're not done yet. After you get access to desktop open command prompt again in elevated mode.

- Type `net user administrator /active:no` and press `Enter`

This is to prevent unauthorized and accidental access to administrator account of your computer. And I recommend it to leave it as it is and don't try to delete, modify or use it as your normal account.

Well that's it. Now you've successfully set up your account. Whew! That was quite a ride isn't it. Great work!

Comment: You're right, thank you, I like this procedure much better than using `netplwiz`. I'll probably do that, but I would like to know about a possible security hole introduced even with this careful steps. They say every software is under some risk. So, for example, the part of deleting an account (even with built-in administrator) could lead to some, even a subtle, problem in a future?

Comment: I tried your solution, but since any account had a password, I had to deal with automatic log in from the last user. So I had to log out after every time I needed to reboot. On `netplwiz` the right option is checked. I remember tweaking a checkbox somewhere else, but I don't whether it was related to some completely different feature.

Comment: @AVP2019 it will not let any security loop holes if you follow the step as mentioned above.

Comment: The automatic log in is a problem that persists on Windows 10 as it is described in this microsoft [question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-to-stop-auto-login-of-last-user-windows-10/1ce4b352-0856-40c0-87a8-2f8ef299007d?page=8)

Comment: @AVP2019 well I don't have the solution for automatic login fix for now. But you can still achieve it by using password in the accounts to prevent it for auto logging. `net user my_user_name my_password` to create password for any or all users and if you want to remove passwords after completing all work then simply type `net user my_user_name *` then it will ask to type password in command but just press enter twice and it will be removed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I set up a new basic account and I saw the Wi-Fi duplicated again. I asked a new [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1460173/why-does-wi-fi-appear-duplicated-after-creating-a-new-user-in-windows-10). In case you are interested.